# mod_rewrite: remove trailing slash for specific files only

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the trailing slash from the urls ending with some file extension only, `.txt`.

Here is the full .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.txt.html
RewriteRule ^(.)\.txt.html /$1.txt [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.)\.txt
RewriteRule ^(.)\.txt $1.txt.html [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.)\.txt/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt\/ $1.txt [R=301]
```

Everything is fine except that the rule for for `.txt/` adds a full path to the url. Is it possible to make it work with relative paths?

For example, this url

`http://test.local:8080/doc/Cons/Bo/Dwnlds/Test.txt/`

goes to this

`http://test.local:8080/Users/dev1/Documents/96/test.org/doc/Cons/Bo/Dwnlds/Test.txt`.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a leading slash to your target as `(.*)` will not contain it, hence the weird file system path as a result:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt\/ /$1.txt [R=301]
```

It actually happens because the RewriteRules defaults to a filesystem path if it exists (in your case, it's hard to tell if your target is an URL-path or a filesystem path because there's no base folder). See the documentation on these at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a go and write back.